How to handle Jest/Axios error without using try/catch?
Is there another way to handle error message while using JS/TS with Axios and Jest in order to get more information why request failed?
For example:
const req = await callApi(payload) 
expect(req.status).toEqual(200)

Let's assume that check above get failed on status 400. With code above you received only Request failed with status code 400 and has no info which validation failed.
I know about try/catch - but something telling me that using try/catch on automation test is not good idea. Maybe I am wrong. Moreover, if you are using try/catch you have to expect status 200 too in catch block, because if you do not use expect there, the test will be facing like success, despite of fact that error occurred.
Another way is using promise - then - construction. Actually it's worse than try/catch, a lot of unnecessary and complex code.
So, is it possible somehow extend error handler / function in Axios or Jest in order to receive info?

You can structure your expectation such that it's against the whole response, e.g. expect(res).toMatchObject({ status: 200 }). If there's a mismatch the entire object gets shown.

interesting, gonna try ...

First, you need to catch the error in the callApi.
For example:
async function callApi(payload) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/api-url', payload);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      throw new Error(`Failed with status ${error.response.status}: ${error.response.data.detail}`);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

Then in Jest, you can use resolves and rejects to handle the success and fail:
test('API succeed with status 200', () => {
  return expect(callApi(payload)).resolves.toHaveProperty('status', 200);
});

test('API fail with status 400 and detailed error', () => {
  return expect(callApi(payload)).rejects.toThrow('Validation details');
});

